# Notation for the action of a matrix applied as right-multiplication?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, notation, group-actions

To show the orbit of $x$ under the action of some matrix $H$ we can write:

$$ x \xrightarrow{H} Hx \xrightarrow{H} H^2x \xrightarrow{H} \cdots $$

where the   '$\text{ }\xrightarrow{H}\text{ }$'  symbol communicates left-multiplication by $H$.

What symbology do we have to show the orbit of an object under right-multiplcation?

e.g. given $F$ and compatible object $z$, do we have arrow symbology for

$$z \to zF \to zF^2 \to \cdots $$

Comment: I like to use $H\cdot$ or $\cdot F$  e.g.

$$ x \xrightarrow{H\cdot} Hx \xrightarrow{H\cdot} H^2x \xrightarrow{H\cdot} \cdots $$

Comment: Being a left-hander, I would use : $...zF^2 \leftarrow zF \leftarrow z$

Comment: @JeanMarie Love it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is a column vector, the matrix $H$ operates on it from the left. If $z$ is a row vector, the matrix $F$ operates on it from the right. Usually, there is only one conventual way to have a matrix act on a vector. I don't think there are enough ambiguous contexts for there to be a conventional disambiguation.

Which is to say, if you need such a notation, either invent one that seems reasonable and use a couple of words to describe it the first time it's being used. Or use a couple of words next to wherever such a chain is written down to specify the direction.

Comment: Yeah, essentially I'm looking for syntax for the orbit of row vectors... I decided to just transpose everything and consider the orbit of a column vector under $F^T$ using the standard $\xrightarrow{F^T}$ notation